# Troubleshooting - Setting up private GitLab server and connecting Gitlab Runners

Tags: ssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab instance running in docker on a dedicated private server (accessible only from within our vpc). We want to start doing CI using Gitlab runners so I spun up another server to host our runners.

Now that Gitlab-Runner has been configured, I try and register a runner with the private IP of the Gitlab server and the registration token

```
Enter the GitLab instance URL (for example, https://gitlab.com/):
$GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP
Enter the registration token:
$TOKEN
Enter a description for the runner:
[BEG-GITLAB-RUNNER]: default
Enter tags for the runner (comma-separated):
default
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=m616FJy- status=couldn't execute POST against https://$GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP/api/v4/runners: Post "https://$GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP/api/v4/runners": x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2022-02-06T20:00:35Z is after 2021-12-24T04:54:28Z
```

It looks like our certs have expired and to verify:

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Nov 24 04:54:28 2021 GMT
notAfter=Dec 24 04:54:28 2021 GMT
```

Gitlab comes with let's encrypt so I decided to enable let's encrypt and cert autorenewal in gitlab rails, however when I try and reconfigure I get the error message:

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

letsencrypt_certificate[$GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 6) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 41) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "$GITLAB_PRIVATE_IP": The ACME server can not issue a certificate for an IP address
```

So it looks like I can't use the let's encrypt option that packaged with gitlab to enable the renewal of certs.

**How can I create/renew ssl certs on a private linux server without a domain?**

**If you've set up Gitlab + Runners on private servers, what does your rails configuration look like?**

**Is there a way to enable DNS on a private server for the sole purpose of a certificate authority granting certs?**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Self-signed certificate I have tested this before and its working fine but require some work. I will try to summarize some of the steps needed:

```
1- generate Self-signed certificate with the domain you choose and make sure to keep it in /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/
2- you need to add the domain and certs path in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
3- reconfigure giltab
4- when connecting the runner make sure to manually copy and activate certs to the runner server .
```

Comment: The anwser seems quite simple, did someone test it ?